# how to get list of disjoint cycles with given permutation?(python)

Tags: python

I have a dictionary for example: `{1:3, 2:2, 3:,1}`. I need to get a list of disjoint cycles of this permutation: `[[1,3], [2]]`.

I know how to get all permutations but I don't know how to delete the ones I already have.
For my example I get: `[[1,3], [2], [3,1]]`.

Comment: please share ur code. what have u tried

Comment: what is meant by disjoint cycle

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to canonicalise your cycle representation by starting at the smallest element of the cycle:

```
min_index = cycle.index(min(cycle))
canonical = cycle[min_index:] + cycle[:min_index]
```

Depending on how you are retrieving cycles, it may be more efficient to only generate the canonical representation.